# Epsilon-greedy action selection question

Tags: epsilon-greedy-policy

Is the following sentence correct?

The estimated values $Q(a)$ do not converge to the true values $q_*(a)$ because $\epsilon$-greedy action selection behaves randomly from time to time.

My Answer: The sentence is wrong since eventually the estimated value $Q(a)$ will converge to $q_*(a)$ and the randomness of epsilon greedy action selection won't be able to influence it if we run it for a long time.
Is my answer correct?

Comment: @Faizy Thanks but could you please explain why? I don't get why randomness is a problem for the convergence of estimated Q to the true value q.

Comment: i think you correct.... Running the epsilon greedy algorithm **for a long time** will minimize the influence of randomness on the estimated value $Q(a)$. The epsilon greedy action randomly selects actions with probability epsilon and otherwise acts greedily with respect to the current estimated value of $Q(a)$. **Over time**, the algorithm will tend to converge on the true values of $q_∗(a)$, since the random actions will be less influential.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that you are correct in saying the sentence is incorrect. Since, as you mention, the epsilon greedy action selection will just allow for the Q values to converge to the optimal q* value since the actions of the policy just provide more observations for Q which will allow for the q* to be converged to. However, this is assuming that the updating of the Q values is in such a way that each new observation has less of an effect on the Q(a). Though it is not the case that the epsilon greedy will converge to the optimal policy/action due to the randomness mentioned by the answer.